# Possible error in Hatfield's "Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, trace, textbook-erratum

In problem 8.1 of Hatfield's *Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings*, the reader is tasked with calculating the trace $$\operatorname {tr}(\gamma_0\frac{(\not p_2 + m)}{2m}\gamma_0\frac{(\not p_1 +m)}{2m}).\tag{problem 8.1}$$ Hatfield says that one should obtain the result  $$\frac 1 {m^2}(8E_1E_2-p_1\cdot p_2 +4m^2),\tag{problem 8.1}$$ where the dot product is that of $4$-vectors. However, when I calculate this trace, I find that I get $$\frac 1 {4m^2}(8E_1E_2 - p_1\cdot p_2 +4m^2),$$ which is off by a factor of $4$. I can find no error in my calculation, and this leads me to believe that Hatfield's calculation is wrong. Which of these is correct?

Edit: Here is my calculation. First we factor out a $\frac 1 {4m^2}$ from the trace to get $$\frac 1 {4m^2}\operatorname {tr}(\gamma_0(\not p_2+m)\gamma_0(\not p_1 +m))=\frac 1 {4m^2}(4m^2 +\operatorname {tr}(\gamma_0\gamma^\mu p_{2\mu}\gamma_0\gamma^\nu p_{1\nu})),$$ since all the trace terms linear in $\not p$ vanish ($\operatorname {tr}\gamma^\mu = 0).$ Next invoke the Clifford algebra to obtain $\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu = 2g^{0\mu}-\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$, insert this into the trace on the RHS, and after much algebra (which is simple to do, provided one recalls the trace identity $\operatorname {tr} \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = 4g^{\mu\nu}$) one finds this equals $$\frac 1 {4m^2}(8p_{2 ,0}p_{1,\nu}g^{0\nu} - 4g^{\mu\nu}p_{2,\mu}p_{1,\nu}+4m^2) =\frac 1 {4m^2}(8E_1E_2-4p_1\cdotp p_2 +4m^2). $$

Comment: Maybe would help if we could see your calculation. Some of us don't have the book to confirm the derivation.

Comment: The book offers no derivation, it's just an exercise. I will edit to put my calculation in.

Comment: @josephh I added the derivation (not all steps, but the key ones)

Comment: I just did the calculation and get $\frac{1}{m^2}(2E_1E_2-\vec p_1\cdot\vec p_2 +m^2)$ which is consistent with yours. His answer **is a typo**. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hatfield says that one should obtain the result  $$\frac 1 {m^2}(8E_1E_2-p_1\cdot p_2 +4m^2)$$

Your steps are correct and *that is* a typo. Omitting the $4m^2$ term in the denominator for now,

$$\text{Tr}\left[\gamma_0(\not\vec p_2+m) \gamma_0(\not\vec p_1+m)\right]=\text{Tr}\left[ (\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0)+\gamma_0 m\gamma_0)(\not\vec p_1+m)\right]$$ Now if you expand this, you'll be left with $$\text{Tr}(\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0\not\vec p_1+\gamma_0m\gamma_0\not\vec p_1 +m\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0+\gamma_0m\gamma_0 m)= \ \text{Tr}(\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0\not\vec p_1+m\not\vec p_1+m\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0+m^2)$$

and if you make no algebraic errors, the term

$$\text{Tr}(\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0\not\vec p_1+m\not\vec p_1+m\gamma_0\not\vec p_2\gamma_0+m^2)$$ leads to the final result $$\frac{1}{m^2}(2E_1E_2-\vec p_1\cdot\vec p_2 +m^2)$$
where the $\frac{1}{4m^2}$ factor is now inserted.
Also, you wrote

> However, when I calculate this trace, I find that I get $$\frac 1 {4m^2}(8E_1E_2 - p_1\cdot p_2 +4m^2),$$

which appears to be missing a coefficient of $4$ on the second term.

Comment: Ah yes, I did forget to put that coefficient in when I typed this up. I did get it in my calculations though. Thank you for your answer and your help!

Comment: No worries and good luck with your studies.